# Selector not working on my swift UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I'm writing a to-do list type app, in order to learn swift for iOS development. I had a settings button on the Navigation bar, on the right side, and whenever a person clicked a button on top of the table view, they could add a new item to their list. That causes a "cancel" button to appear on the left side of the bar and a "add" button to appear on the right side. When the person is done, however, those buttons disappear, and so I programatically re-create the settings button, with a call to a function that is supposed to call the segue.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "modify"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: Selector("showSettings:"))
```

This is the code that creates the button on the navbar (and it is indeed created)

```
 func showSettings(sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("segueShouldBeDone!")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showSettings", sender: sender)
}
```

And this is the function that is supposed to call the segue (I added the print to see if it was at least being called, and it isn't).

I've had this same problem in another place in my code, but I had given up on fixing it cause it wasn't that important for me then. But now it is interfering with how the app works, so I wanted to know how to fix it.

Any help would be great.

Comment: @LeoDabus Although you're right and I should have done that, it actually did't change anything, which kind of boggles me. The image was being shown already.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `showSettings:` selector isn't being called because you specified `nil` instead of `self` for the bar button item's target. Change the line to:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "modify"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("showSettings:"))
```

This assume the `showSettings:` method is in the same class that contains this line of code.

Read the documentation for this initializer, specifically the info about the `target` parameter.

Comment: Yep, that did solve it. But even when my `showSettings` function didn't take any parameters (and I used "showSettings" as a selector), it didn't work. Does the segue sender have to be different from `nil`? The other place I was using it in (as mentioned in the question), it didn't take any parameters, and the function also wasn't getting called. That confuses me because I used it to create the "Add" and "Cancel" buttons with `target: nil`, and they work fine.

Comment: Passing `self` instead of `nil` to the `UIBarButtonItem` initializer has absolutely nothing at all to do with the `sender` parameter passed to your `showSettings:` method and nothing at all to do with the segue.

Comment: Why did my other UIBarButtonItems work when they had target `nil`, and these other two didn't? Any ideas?

Comment: They couldn't have. If you pass `nil` as the `target`, then the `selector` will never be called. It can't unless `target` is set to a proper non-nil value.

Comment: Could that be a bug with Swift? Something like that? Because they work exactly how they were supposed to, even though I pass nil as target. I'll change that now, in order not to cause problems in the future, but they were working well. Anyways, thanks for the help :)